# Unknown column '$userId' in 'where clause

Tags: mysql

anyone know how to fix this? what am i doing wrong i am bad at english sorry
the link is to see my code, hope it helps

```
SELECT Beskeder.Id, Beskeder.Overskrift, Beskeder.Besked, Kategorier.Kategorinavn 
FROM Beskeder 
INNER JOIN Kategorier
    ON Beskeder.FK_KategoriId = Kategorier.Id
WHERE Beskeder.FK_brugerId = $userId 
ORDER BY Beskeder.Id DESC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

MySQL returned: Documentation

```
#1054 - Unknown column '$userId' in 'where clause'**
```

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2vngfwy&s=9#.WT2RDpDyhPY

this error i get if i try on site 
Notice: Undefined index: userId in C:\Xampp\htdocs\initializr_soren\admin\index.php on line 222
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY Beskeder.Id DESC' at line 5

line 222 is: $userId = $_SESSION["userId"];

Comment: You have a php variable in your where clause. Replace it with a string literal.

Comment: What does the echo return?

Comment: And if you do {$userId} ? And turn that echo tosee the QUERY

Comment: please edit your question and add php tag and add commented code in to description. Then someone can give you nice and clear answer.

Comment: Please don't put code in the comments. It's almost unreadable. Edit your question and put the info there.

Comment: Which line is 222? If it's the line where you set $userId to the session variable, then that's the problem. The value doesn't exist, so $userId will be undefined.

Comment: $userId = $_SESSION["userId"];

is line 222

Answer (score 0):

You can only use PHP variables in a QUERY like that if you enclose it with "

**Example**:

```
"SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE `id` = $userId";
```

Btw, it is a risc for sql-injection.

Comment: Make sure it's in double quotes - if your using single quotes the substitution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a SQL query which contains input from the user, use prepared statements to build such a query and fill it with the user data. Depending on the programming language and the library you use, you might want to use [`PDO::prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: sorry i cant understand you guys

i get this error also

Notice: Undefined index: userId in C:\Xampp\htdocs\initializr_soren\admin\index.php on line 222
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY Beskeder.Id DESC' at line 5

Answer (score 0):

if you are running on phpmyadmin or mysql workbench then replace $userid with value..if not then it should be treated as string or should be in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
#1054 - Unknown column '$userId' in 'where clause'**
```

This error shows you because your table does not contain column using this name.

`$userId` is your variable and you cannot add variable to a query like this. Either you can wrap whole query using double quote(`""`) or you can combine those like below,

```
$query = "SELECT Beskeder.Id, Beskeder.Overskrift, Beskeder.Besked, Kategorier.Kategorinavn 
          FROM Beskeder INNER JOIN Kategorier ON Beskeder.FK_KategoriId = Kategorier.Id WHERE Beskeder.FK_brugerId = " .$userId ." 
          ORDER BY Beskeder.Id DESC
          LIMIT 0, 25";
```

Rather than `Beskeder.Id` access table column like this you can do like below:

```
$query = "SELECT b.Id, b.Overskrift, b.Besked, k.Kategorinavn 
          FROM Beskeder AS b INNER JOIN Kategorier AS k ON b.FK_KategoriId = k.Id WHERE b.FK_brugerId = " .$userId ." 
          ORDER BY b.Id DESC
          LIMIT 0, 25";
```

This is called [**alias**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)) - `Kategorier k`: simply refer table name using `k`

Answer (score 0):

it seems there wasnt really anything wrong, just forgot i wasnt logged in.
so the code i had was all right :/